# Getting previous versions of files using C#

Tags: c#, filesystems

I am trying to restore files from windows backups programmatically and need to get all of the previous versions of the files that windows has stored as backups. The actual restoration will be done using the filepath that windows is given and will be done in powershell, however what I want to do is display to a user all of the previous versions that are available to them.

Is there an easy way to do this using C#? Or do I just have to test the path using the date that the versioning system appends to the file path? I.E "@GMT-2017.03.20-12.00.30" (Using this method I would have to try every possible time the backup could have happened which could affect performance)

Basically what I want is to get exactly what is in the "previous versions" tab in the file system.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Looking deeper it looks like the backup time is pretty consistent so I doubt I would have to guess, I would still like a more elegant solution if there is one available though.

**Edit 2:**

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/643536/how-to-find-and-open-previous-versions-of-a-folder-programmatically-using-power) which is a potential solution, not the one I'm looking for but the solution I want might not exist.

Comment: There is no documented api for this.  Probably not in the least because this feature was changed dramatically in Win8, that does not look like a Win8+ screenshot.

Comment: It's windows server 2008. I think I'll just have to iterate over the snapshots and find what I want manually. I was hoping  there would just be something nice and simple in the System.IO library but looks like I'm out of luck.